# jQuery remove() removes only the first row

Tags: jquery

Im having some trouble with adding and removing fields in a form table. Its a simple code as i am kind of new to this.

```
    <table id="lisa_pakkumine_tabel">
        <tr>
            <td>Vali hange: <?php getlisthange();?></td>
            <td><button class="add_field_button">Lisa rida</button></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th>Vali pakkuja</th>
            <th>Sisesta maksumus</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><?php getlistpakkuja();?></td>
            <td><input type='text' name='pakkumuse_maksumus[]'/><a href="#"class="remove_field">Eemalda rida</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table><br>
    <input type="submit" value="LISA PAKKUMINE">


jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('button.add_field_button').click(function(){
        $('table#lisa_pakkumine_tabel tr:last').clone().appendTo('table#lisa_pakkumine_tabel');
        return false;
    });
});

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('.remove_field').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    });
});
```

The idea is to clone a field row which has php function in it (populating select list from mysql), as you can't call php from jquery im using cloning. Adding rows works but when trying to remove them it only removes the first one and does nothing with the other rows. So basicly it only removes the original row(s).

EDIT:

Comment: Any special reason you have two document ready events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're adding rows dynamically, the handler you've assigned is only assigned to the row that exists when you hook it up. What you want to do is handle the click via event delegation, rooted in the table:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $("#lisa_pakkumine_tabel").on("click", ".remove_field", function() {
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    });
});
```

That hooks the click event on the table, but tells jQuery to only fire our handler if the click passed through a `.remove_field` element on its way to the table when bubbling.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('.remove_field').click(function(){
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: "try this" answers are not useful. Say *what* you changed, and *why*. (Morover, this won't help.)